# Hiding component detail on selection

Tags: autodesk-forge

When we select a component in the viewer, it is highlighted and all the edges on the component are shown - including internal fillets, welds, etc. I think this was introduced to the viewer a few versions back. How do we turn this off, so that only the external geometry is shown? In the screenshot you can see that when the component is selected it becomes transparent and shows internal detail of the component. We want the detail to remain hidden.

[image]

Comment: You can disable line/edge rendering in the viewer settings panel, but I'm afraid that the highlighting of internal features (the default behavior) cannot be disabled. One way to work around this would be to basically disable the selection entirely (using the viewer's `disableSelection` method). Would that work for you?

Comment: Hi Petr, unfortunately we need selection to be enabled for the components in question. I've seen demos where we can control the colour of selected components - is it possible to also control the opacity of the selection programatically?

Comment: You're right @Chris, color of the selection highlight can be adjusted using the `setSelectionColor` method, but the opacity is not configurable at the moment. There's just a "hacky" way that I'll explain in an answer to this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it is only possible to configure the selection highlight color (using the `setSelectionColor` method) but not the opacity. The only way around this would be to hack the internals of the viewer implementation - it uses 2 passes to render the selection, one pass for visible parts, and one pass for hidden parts. After commenting out the second pass, you'd get the desired appearance.